# Problem with refreshing ListAdapter of RecycleView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, mutablelivedata

I am trying to observe MutableLiveData and refresh the RecycleView, but it doesn't work. This is my fragment code:

```
class NowyZestaw : Fragment() {

    val setEditModeViewModel: SetEditModeViewModel by activityViewModels()
    


    @VisibleForTesting(otherwise = VisibleForTesting.PRIVATE)
    val bazaModel: BazaModel by activityViewModels()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nowy_zestaw, container, false)
        root.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.flashcard_recycler).isNestedScrollingEnabled = false
        return root
    }

    @SuppressLint("ShowToast")
    override fun onViewCreated(root: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val addFlashcard: Button = root.findViewById(R.id.dodajFiszke)
        addFlashcard.setOnClickListener {
            val fiszka = Fiszka(0, "test", "test", 1)
//            bazaModel.dodajFiszke(fiszka)
            setEditModeViewModel.addNewFlashcard(Fiszka(1, "raz", "raz", 1))
        }

        val recyclerView: RecyclerView = root.findViewById(R.id.flashcard_recycler)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(root.context)

        val adapter = SetAdapter()
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter

        setEditModeViewModel.flashcards.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { flashcardList ->
            Log.d("ANDROID", flashcardList.size.toString())
            adapter.submitList(flashcardList)
        })
    }
}
```

This is my view model:

```
class SetEditModeViewModel : ViewModel() {

    val flashcards = MutableLiveData<MutableList<Fiszka>>().apply {
        value = mutableListOf()
    }

    fun addNewFlashcard(item: Fiszka) {
        flashcards.value?.add(item)
        flashcards.value = flashcards.value
    }
}
```

and xml lines:

```
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/flashcard_recycler"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:listitem="@layout/nowa_fiszka" />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

When I click the button in console appears the correct size of list, so it means that observed is notified. When I for example change the smartphone orientation items appear in recycle view. What is more, if I observe Room database, that returns LiveData<List> everything works correct. Maybe it works only with LiveData<List>, not with MutableLiveData<MutableList>, but I have no idea why it happens. To sum up, I would like new item appers in RecyclerView after I click the button. Could somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

In your observer you should call notifyDataSetChanged();

```
    setEditModeViewModel.flashcards.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { flashcardList ->
        Log.d("ANDROID", flashcardList.size.toString())
        adapter.submitList(flashcardList)
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  // This is needed
    })
```

Comment: `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` is not necesseri, becouse you call `adapter.submitList()`. When you use `MutableList` and update item, you have still same reference on Object in heap. You have to use `List` or create new Collection and then pass it in `submitList()`